# Place for AlertDialog in Android app based on MVP architecture

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, mvp

Can anyone tell me where should I put AlertDialogs in my app according to MVP architecture? Should I leave them in my Activity or put to presenter?

Comment: To get better feeling on what's on P and what's on V, just think of your presenter as a non-Android module that could be shared with different implementations (Android, Swing, JavaFX, etc). So the answer is pretty self-answering, in principle: V.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv yes, thanks. Please put it as answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As MVP is not a specific platform principle, it can be used to write platform-agnostic applications. Since M and P are pretty easy to be written in plain Java (not always true for M, but almost always true for P), V is practically a component of the target platform (say, Swing, GWT, JavaFX, Android, and even CLI [command line interface]). Suppose you write such a cross-platform application and you have a specific view, `INotificationView` that is declared as follows:

```java
public interface INotificationView {

    void reportError(@Nonnull String errorMessage);

}
```

Your base platform-agnostic P does not known anything on which platform it's being executed or supposed to be executed on (at least at the compile-time), and it only holds a reference to an `INotificationView` instance. Thus you can inject platform-specific views like:

```java
public final class AndroidNotificationView
        extends Activity
        implements INotificationView {

    @Override
    public void reportError(@Nonnull final String errorMessage) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR: " errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Note that this approach lets you to write regular unit tests for your presenters as it holds no platform-specific dependencies anymore. Another point is, let's say, you port your application to CLI, so the interface above might be implemented as follows:

```java
public final class CliNotificationView
        implements INotificationView {

    @Override
    public void reportError(@Nonnull final String errorMessage) {
        System.err.print("ERROR: ");
        System.err.println(errormessage);
    }

}
```

Pretty different than the Android implementation, right? This is basically what MVP is about.

Also note, that the name of the notification view method is not named `displayError` or `showError` or `showAlertDisplay` just because the view interface does not dictate *how* the error will be notified to a user -- it's still  *error reporting somehow* from the V perspective.

Thus, you can easily put your `AlertDialog` to your view implementation.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer.

Comment: How would you handle situations where an operation must be performed after the user acknowledges the error? E.g. an unrecoverable error where the presenter must close the view after the user dismisses the dialog or presses "any key to continue"

Comment: @NicholasLythall I would just add another parameter to the `reportError` method accepting a listener, say `void reportError(@Nonnull String message, @Nonnull Runnable onAcknowledged)` (or any other listener type that matches your needs the best). And then, in the presenter: `view.reportError("Unrecoverable error", view::shutdown)`; and in the view: `dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Acknowledge", (di, i) -> onAcknowledged.run())`.

Comment: Hi Lyubomyr. Very informative answer. Just have a minor question -- in a scenario where the (custom) dialog needs a callback listener, which one implements it, the V or P? Currently, I had it done where P is implementing it and I pass the presenter when creating the dialog (e.g. CustomDialog(this, presenter). Does that make sense? Cheers!